# Spring Integration, delete file in outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring, integration, delete-file, channel, outbound

I am using Spring Integration to poll a directory for a File, process this file in a service class, write this file to an output directory and then delete the original file.

I have the following XML configuration:

```
  <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInChannel"
                                    directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/input" 
                                    auto-create-directory="true"  >
      <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="1000" />
  </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int:service-activator id="servicActivator"
                         input-channel="filesInChannel"
                         output-channel="filesOut"
                         ref="my_file_processing_service">
  </int:service-activator>

  <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter  id="filesOut" auto-create-directory="true" delete-source-files="true" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/output"/>
```

This polls the file, passes it to my processing_service and copies it to the outbound directory. However the original file is not being deleted. Does anyone have any idea as to why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that the question was asked a long time ago but maybe the answer will be useful to someone else.

The reason why the input file is not deleted is provided in the [Spring Integration Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#file-outbound-channel-adapter):

> The `delete-source-files` attribute will only have an effect if the
>   inbound Message has a File payload or if the `FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE`
>   header value contains either the source File instance or a String
>   representing the original file path.

Your message does not contain this particular header. If you use one of the [standard file transformers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#file-transforming) (`FileToStringTransformer` and `FileToByteArrayTransformer`) it will be set automatically. Alternatively you can set it manually using a [header enricher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#header-enricher).

[Behind the scenes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/transformer/AbstractFilePayloadTransformer.java?source=cc) something like this is happening in the file transformers:

```
...
Message<?> transformedMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(result)
        .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
        .setHeaderIfAbsent(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, file)
        .setHeaderIfAbsent(FileHeaders.FILENAME, file.getName())
        .build();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html

```
<int-file:outbound-gateway id="mover" request-channel="moveInput"
reply-channel="output"
directory="${output.directory}"
mode="REPLACE" delete-source-files="true"/>
```

I don't know how to do this on the inbound-channel-adapter(which I think makes sense)