# Chaining together channels removes the file_originalFile header

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a requirement where I want to use ftp and put the file in a dynamic local-directory. I also want to add a age filter. That is not allow the old files through. This works with file properly. I added a custom filter and checked the File objects creation date using this code:

```
int ageLimit = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("file.age"));
        BasicFileAttributes view = null;
        try
        {
            view = Files.getFileAttributeView(
                    Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()),
                    BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileTime ft = view.creationTime();
        if (((new Date()).getTime() - (((ft.to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))/* / 10000L) - 11644473600000L*/))) > ageLimit
                * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))// file creation
                                        // date(converted
                                        // to
                                        // java.util.date)
                                        // - current
                                        // date >
                                        // oldness in ms
        {
            logger.info("File is old:" + (f.getName()));
            return false;
        }
```

This works fine for int-file adapter. But when I added ftp support, the object I got in the payload was an FTPFile object. This does not give the creationdate but gives the last modified date. The last modified date is not usefull for me. Hence I had to configure the ftp and then chain the file adapter to the directory.

1. the int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter picks up a file from the ftp site and puts it in a local directory.
2. This file is picked up by the int-file:inbound-channel-adapter and put in the final destination.

This is a two step process to pickup a file put in the ftp location.

The filter class works on the  int-file:inbound-channel-adapter. This chaining is working.

The problem is in deletion of the original files. The ftp site file(remote-directory) gets deleted automatically. The local-directory file which is picked up by the int-file:inbound-channel-adapter does not get deleted.

This is my configuration.

```
     <int:channel id="ftpChannel"/> 
 <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="." 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
    />  
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"

    local-directory="file:${paths.root}"
    delete-remote-files="true"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    remote-directory="."
     filename-pattern="*${file.char}*${file.char}*${file.char}*${file.char}*${file.char}*"

    preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
        <bean id="ftpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${ftp.ip}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>

        <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="abc" id="filesOut"
        directory-expression="@outPathBean.getPath()"
        delete-source-files="true" filename-generator="fileNameGenerator" />

 <int:header-enricher input-channel="ftpChannel" output-channel="ftpChannel">
    <int:header name="file_originalFile"  ref="getPath" method="getCurrentPath" />
</int:header-enricher>

        <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${paths.root}" channel="abc" filter="compositeFilter" >
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />

    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:channel id="abc"/>
```

The customfilefilter and filenamegenerator beans are also defined.

I have added the header-enricher to add the file_originalFile header as I read somewhere that this header is dropped if the file is used twice/   chained like in my situation. Though the beans method gets called and I have written the following code in it, the file does not get deleted from the file adapters source directory.

```
public String getCurrentPath(Message<File> payload)
{


    File f = payload.getPayload();
    if (payload.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE)== null)
    {
        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    else
    {
        payload.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE).toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?? I have tried using the header-enricher for abc channel as well with not luck!

Hope the problem is clear now.. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, it isn't crear yet what's going on. Explain, please, you requirement and which issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to:

> Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] to required type [org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel] for property 'outputChannel': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Since you have `<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound" channel="ftpChannel"`

You should you use the **channel** bean name for the `<int:transformer id="testTransformer" input-channel="ftpInbound"`, rather an `id` of that adapter  `<int:transformerd="testTransformer" input-channel="ftpChannel"`

Comment: Sorry, noticed mistakes in my answer. Yes, you have to use `ftpChannel` from `<transformer>`

Comment: done that. Can I detect the source directory from the payload? If so I can use a common transformer for both the paths

Comment: If your `payload` is `File`, of course, you can get its `absolutePath` to extract the `dir`.

Comment: The directory is the local directory specified. Not the remote directory. returning it in the bean method of the header-enricher is not deleting the file in the local directory

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your question is.

That said, Spring Integration 3.0 [introduced the `local-filter` on the (s)ftp adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/history.html#3.0-(s)ftp-changes) which should allow you to use your custom filter there.

To remove the local file using the header, you can use a request handler advice, see the [retry-and-more](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) sample for more information.

Your exception is because you are injecting the outbound adapter as the transformer's `output-channel`; you should inject `ftpChannel` instead.

Comment: i am sending the channel now and it is not giving any exception. Will edit my q for clarity

Comment: Why are you adding the header? It's not used in this context. Using the `ftpChannel` as the input and output channel on the enricher is not good practice. It will work in this case, but I wouldn't recommend it; use discrete channels. Is the destination on the same disk? If it is, the adapter simply renames the input file; if not, it will copy and delete (and write an INFO log). I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what your issue is.

Comment: I read somewhere that the header if not present will lead to the source file not being deleted. Thats why I tried using the enricher. Yes the destination is on the same disk as the local-directory. It could be a mapped network path too right? So what is the reason my file wont get deleted from the local-directory?? Any inputs?

Comment: Like I said, the adapter first attempts to rename the file and if that fails it copies and deletes the original. So, if it's on the same disk, it should be renamed ok. Take a look at the logs.

Comment: This is the question which I thought was relevant:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707149/spring-integration-delete-file-in-outbound-channel-adapter

Comment: Yes, but in your case, you have a `File` payload; as cited in that answer: "The `delete-source-files` attribute will only have an effect if the inbound __Message has a File payload__ or if the FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE header value contains either the source File instance or a String representing the original file path." (my emphasis).

Comment: So it should automatically have worked in my case...Am I right?

Comment: Yes; I just ran a test and it worked fine for me (https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration/commit/dc2dfc669b39ed0901bfe46485aa38da390d28b4). On reviewing your question, it appears you are using the same `ftpChannel` in bot places - you have both the ftp outbound adapter AND the header enricher subscribed to the same channel. That means 50% of the files will go directly to the outbound adapter.

Comment: ideally i should remove the header enricher as the added header is not useful right?

Comment: Of course; it adds no value and complicates the configuration.